# Understand how this simplification of absolute value expression works

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

The task in the following problem is to prove the implication using the Triangle Inequality:

> Show that $|b|<\frac{1}{2} \implies |b^3-1|>\frac{7}{8}$.

I tried the following:

---

- By the Triangle Inequality:

$$
|b^3-1| \ge ||b^3|-|1|| = \color{blue}{ ||b^3|-1| \ge |b|^3-1 }
$$

- Since $|b|<\frac{1}{2} \implies |b|^3<\frac{1}{8} \implies |b|^3 - 1<-\frac{7}{8}$

---

But that's not correct. I went wrong at blue, highlighted part, in the solution provided in my book they do it differently:

$$
|b^3-1| \ge ||b^3|-|1|| = \color{blue}{ ||b^3|-1| \ge 1-|b|^3 }
$$

I understand that when proofing such inequalities, it's good to simplify as much as possible to make the variable, here $|b|$, stand outside of absolute values. But I can't follow here why this simplification was allowed.

Is this based on some rule how to resolve absolute values? I can't seem to get the reasoning why they could do $... \ge 1-|b|^3$ instead of $... \ge |b|^3-1$ what I tried.

Comment: In the blue highlighted part you and the book used $|x|\ge x$ and $|x|\ge -x$ both of which are correct but the one used by book made the inequality stronger ,what you did was not wrong but it was just not enough.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore you are right ... I got it now, it looked like magic at first.

Comment: Is there a way we could've seen to solve the way the book did or is it basically trial and error?

Comment: yes of course  without even doing any inequality mess it is easy to see that $1-|b|^3>0$ hence $\color{blue}{||b|^3-1|=1-|b|^3}$ as $|x|=-x $ if $x\le 0$

Comment: You are not wrong. But you have $|b^3 - 1| \ge |b|^3 - 1$ and that $|b|^3 - 1 < -\frac 78$.  But you can't combine those.  After all if $a > b$ and $b < M$ then what can we say about $a$?  Not. much.  But we also have $|b^3-1| \ge 1-|b|^3$ and $1-|b|^3 > \frac 78$ and that can be combined.  If you have $a > c$ and $c > K$ what can you say about $a$ now? Well, now you can say $a > K$.

Comment: Alterhnative.  $|b| < \frac 12\implies -\frac 12 < b < \frac 12 \implies -\frac 18 < b^3 < \frac 18\implies -\frac 98 < b^3-1 < -\frac 78 <0\implies \frac 78 < |b^3 -1| < \frac 98$.

Comment: +1 to fleablood's last comment, which is exactly how I would have solved it.  No need for anything fancy.

Comment: TBH I also like this way better. Much easier to follow.

Comment: Any resources on the internet or any books that teach how to solve inequalities? I'm really quite bad at them still and can't seem to get the hang out of it based on how the material is presented in my current course.